# When I redirect the user from ShareExtensions to the App, the App opens but then instantly closes

Tags: swift, share-extension

As written in the subject, I would like to redirect the user to my App when he's using share extensions. For example when he tries to share a photo through my app - he opens the images, clicks on share, selects my app and then he is redirected to the app. He is in fact, but when he is, the app opens and then instantly closes. I made the solution in reference to this: 
https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/

(adding all the necessary stuff in plist)

And in Share Extensions I made the following function:

```
func redirectToApp() {
    let urlString = "myAppName://"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")
    let context = NSExtensionContext()
    context.open(url! as URL, completionHandler: nil)

    var responder = self as UIResponder?

    while (responder != nil) {
        if responder?.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) == true {
            responder?.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
        }
        responder = responder!.next
    }
}
```

Comment: Your app is opening, so in theory the share extension is working. but your app is crashing when handling the link, you should check your app can handle the links

Comment: you're right. Could have thought about it

Comment: I can redirect to the app by inputting the same link in the safari on my iPhone. Web links or links to App Store work as well. Am I checking it wrong? Don't really have an idea

Comment: Check in the open url method. Probably there the issue. Your app is not able to open the url properly